# Adding a column to pandas dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a personal project collecting the data on Covid-19 cases. The data set only shows the total number of Covid-19 cases per state cumulatively. I would like to add a column that contains the new cases added that day. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np

#read the CSV from github
hist_US_State = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv")

#some code to get yesterday's date and the day before which is needed later.
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = str(yesterday)
day_before_yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 2)
day_before_yesterday = str(day_before_yesterday)

#Extracting yesterday's and the day before cases and combine them in one dataframe
yesterday_cases = hist_US_State[hist_US_State["date"] == yesterday]
day_before_yesterday_cases = hist_US_State[hist_US_State["date"] == day_before_yesterday]

total_cases = pd.DataFrame()
total_cases = day_before_yesterday_cases.append(yesterday_cases)

#Adding a new column called "new_cases" and this is where I get into trouble.
total_cases["new_cases"] = yesterday_cases["cases"] - day_before_yesterday_cases["cases"]
```

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What’s the issue?

Comment: I don't end up with the new column that contains yesterday's cases of one state - the day before yesterday's cases of one state. My end goal is to add a column that contains the number of covid-19 cases added that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defined `total_cases` as a concatenation (via append) of `yesterday_cases` and `day_before_yesterday_cases`, its number of rows is equal to the sum of the other two dataframes. It looks like `yesterday_cases` and  `day_before_yesterday_cases` both have 55 rows, and so `total_cases` has 110 rows. Thus your last line is trying to assign 55 values to a series of 110 values.

You may either want to reshape your data so that each date is its own column, or work in arrays of dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not sure if you completely understand me. I am trying to add a new column when the state matches and fill the new column with the yesterday's cases of one state - the day before yesterday's cases of one state. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes so you need to reshape the data. There are some ways to do this. Here's on implementation using pivot_table.
 `daily_cases = total_cases.pivot_table(index = ['state', 'fips'], columns = 'date', values = 'cases')`

`daily_cases['difference'] = daily_cases[yesterday] - daily_cases[day_before_yesterday]`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for that explanation